# Regular expression to check if IP is found on 2 ranges

Tags: python, regex, perl

Is it possible to write a regular expression as one expression to check if an IP is found on 2 ranges?

I can do this in 2 steps:

```
if ($ip =~ /$range1/ and $ip =~ /$range2/ ) {
    print "intersection"
}
```

but I wonder if it's possible to do this in one regex:

```
if ($ip =~ /$my_regex/ ) {
    print "intersection";
}
```

Comment: How about providing some example data? What do your $range1, $range2 and $ip strings look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a solution in Perl.

Why not use `NetAddr::IP` and let it handle the thing? For example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use NetAddr::IP;
my @addresses = (
    new NetAddr::IP '216.239.32.0/255.255.32.0',
    new NetAddr::IP '64.157.227.255/255.255.252.0'
);
my $banned = 0;
my $visitor_address = NetAddr::IP->new($visitor_ip);
foreach my $banned_address (@addresses) {
    if ($visitor_address->within $banned_address) {
       $banned = 1;
       last;
    }
}
```

Read the documentation and available methods at: [https://metacpan.org/pod/NetAddr::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/NetAddr%3a%3aIP)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Module [`NetAddr::IP`](http://p3rl.org/NetAddr%3a%3aIP):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use NetAddr::IP;

my @addresses = (
    NetAddr::IP->new('192.168.172.1/255.255.0.0'),
    NetAddr::IP->new('10.1.0.0/255.0.0.0'),
);

my $address_to_check = NetAddr::IP->new($IP_TO_CHECK);

foreach my $address_in_list (@addresses) {
  if ($address_to_check->within $address_in_list) {
    # do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to join two independent subexpressions into a single regex using lookahead assertions:

```
if ($ip =~ /^(?=.*$range1)(?=.*$range2)/s ) {
    print "intersection"
}
```

However, if you really are dealing with IP addresses, you should use a module like [`NetAddr::IP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/NetAddr%3a%3aIP).